# Proving an iterative algorithm with recursive functions (Dafny)

Tags: dafny

I have this algorithm that computes the product of the unique numbers in a given integer array:

```
method UniqueProduct(a: array<int>) returns (product: int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures product == ProductOfUniques(a[..])
{
    var p := 1;
    var seen: seq<int> := [];
    
    for i := 0 to a.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant forall x :: x in seen ==> x in a[..i]
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i && a[k] !in seen ==> seen == a[..i]
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i && a[k] !in seen ==> p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i])
//        invariant p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i])
    {
        if !(a[i] in seen) {
            seen := seen + [a[i]];
            p := p * a[i];
        }
        assert a[..i+1][..i] == a[..i];
        assert forall k :: 0 <= k < |seen| ==> seen[k] in a[..i+1];
        assert a[i] !in seen ==> p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i+1]) == ProductOfUniques(a[..i]+[a[i]]);
        assert a[i] in seen <== p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i]);
    }
    assert a[..a.Length] == a[..];
    assert a[a.Length-1] !in seen ==> p == ProductOfUniques(a[..a.Length]) == ProductOfUniques(a[..a.Length-1]+[a[a.Length-1]]);

    assert a[a.Length-1] in seen <== p == ProductOfUniques(a[..a.Length-1]+[a[a.Length-1]]);

//    assert p == ProductOfUniques(a[..]);
    product := p;
}
```

And these functions:

```
ghost function ProductOfUniques(a: seq<int>) : int
{
    if |a| == 0 then 1 
    else Multiply(a, [])
}

ghost function Multiply(numbers: seq<int>, seen: seq<int>) : int
    requires |numbers| > 0
{
    var tail := numbers[|numbers|-1];
    if |numbers| == 1 then 
        if tail in seen then 1 else tail 
    else 
        Multiply(numbers[..|numbers|-1], seen + [tail]) * (if tail in seen then 1 else tail) 
}
```

All the individual assertions and invariants hold, but the method's postcondition does not verify. I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to convince Dafny to assert that this is true `p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i])`.

I tried writing a lemma that would assert

```
lemma X(a: seq<int>, i: int, n: int)
    requires |a| > 0
    requires 0 < i < |a|
    ensures n in a[..i] ==> ProductOfUniques(a[..i]) == ProductOfUniques(a[..i] + [n])
```

But this also led me to a dead end.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following two lemmas of `for` loop are valid by being vacuous.

```
invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i && a[k] !in seen ==> seen == a[..i]
invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i && a[k] !in seen ==> p == ProductOfUniques(a[..i])
```

If you replace conclusion with `false` it still goes through like shown below

```
invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i && a[k] !in seen ==> false
```

This means these two invariants are not that useful.

There is data structure in dafny which holds unique element namely set. In solution below I will be using set instead of sequence.

With program below I am getting verification error that third invariant is not being maintained.

```
method UniqueProduct (arr: array<int>) returns (product: int)
   ensures product == SetProduct((set i | 0 <= i < arr.Length :: arr[i]))
{
    var p := 1;
    var seen: set<int> := {};
    
    for i := 0 to arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
        invariant seen == (set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k])
        invariant p == SetProduct((set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k]))
    {
        if ! (arr[i] in seen) {
            seen := seen + { arr[i] };
            p := p * arr[i];
        }
    }
    product := p;
}

ghost function SetProduct(s : set<int>) : int
{
    if s == {} then 1
    else var x :| x in s; 
         x * SetProduct(s - {x})
}
```

This means Dafny need some help to prove invariant being maintained. To assure myself that I am following right path I added below lemma without proof and invoke `SetProductLemma(seen, arr[i])` as last statement inside if, it goes through.

```
lemma SetProductLemma(s: set <int>, x: int) 
 requires x in s
 ensures SetProduct(s - {x}) * x == SetProduct(s)
```

Now proving SetProductLemma is little tricky due to :| operator. I would point to read
https://leino.science/papers/krml274.html.

Full program is listed below

```
method UniqueProduct (arr: array<int>) returns (product: int)
   ensures product == SetProduct((set i | 0 <= i < arr.Length :: arr[i]))
{
    var p := 1;
    var seen: set<int> := {};
    
    for i := 0 to arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
        invariant seen == (set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k])
        invariant p == SetProduct((set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k]))
    {
        if ! (arr[i] in seen) {
            seen := seen + { arr[i] };
            p := p * arr[i];
            SetProductLemma(seen, arr[i]);
        }
    }
    product := p;
}

ghost function SetProduct(s : set<int>) : int
{
    if s == {} then 1
    else var x :| x in s; 
         x * SetProduct(s - {x})
}

lemma SetProductLemma(s: set <int>, x: int) 
 requires x in s
 ensures SetProduct(s - {x}) * x == SetProduct(s)
{
   if s != {}
   {
      var y :| y in s && y * SetProduct(s - {y}) == SetProduct(s);
      if y == x {}
      else {
         calc {
            SetProduct(s);
            y * SetProduct(s - {y});
            { SetProductLemma(s - {y}, x); }
            y * x * SetProduct(s - {y} - {x});
            { assert s - {x} - {y} == s - {y} - {x};}
            y * x * SetProduct(s - {x} - {y});
            x * y * SetProduct(s - {x} - {y});
            { SetProductLemma(s - {x}, y); }
            x * SetProduct(s - {x});
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand: `var x :| x in s;  x * SetProduct(s - {x})` takes, what, *one any* element from s, or *the first element* from s? If it's *one any*, how does this match the order of the traversal of the iterative traversal?

Comment: It is any element from s. I don't fully understand your second question fully. It is connected using invariant `p == SetProduct((set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k]))`

Comment: If I change the loop (and only the loop) to `for i := arr.Length downto 0 `, then the second loop invariant `seen == (set k | 0 <= k < i :: arr[k]) does not hold. So there's something about order of the set elements that's implicitly assumed.

Comment: Yes that sets are built from sequence from left to right. But In definition of multiplication order of multiplication is arbitrary. But by first fact it matches order of traversal of iteration

Comment: OK. Changing the order of the loop, we must also change the set comprehension `set k | i <= k < arr.Length :: arr[k]` In this case, the program verifies. I get it now. The way I was doing it, I needed to prove equality of two ordered sequences, and that's much harder than proving that an ordered sequence is a always a given set.